# Raspberry Pi browser won't start on startup

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2, autostart

I want my browser to start on startup. At the moment it works quite randomly. On some boots the browser flashes quickly and is running in the background. When this happens, I can't start a new browser session before I kill the existing one.

How can I prevent this from happening? I'm currently doing this with a shell script, but I've also tried the autostart method and both give me same results.

Comment: Can you show us your shell script?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was also starting up a VNC server on the startup, and the browser session went there instead. Disabled VNC on boot, and it seems to be ok now.

Comment: The shell script I used for browser was as simple as: sleep 10s chromium-- kiosk url